# Sharepoint solution failing to retract

Tags: solution-package, retraction

When I try to retract solution (via Central Administration or using `stsadm`), the solution stays in the Retracting state.

I found a very similar question [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676557/unable-to-retract-sharepoint-solutions), but the services 'Windows SharePoint Services Administration' and 'Windows SharePoint Services Timer' are running, and restarting them didn't help.

Running the command `stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs` returns the message "Operation completed successfully." but the solution is still retracting. Interestingly, running that command produces the following log entries:

> Service Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationService, id [GUID] not online, ignoring

> Service Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService, id [GUID] not online, ignoring

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from Kai (slightly amended):

> Eventually I had to reinstall WSS3. It seems the problem occurred because I changed the user accounts the Admin and Timer services ran under from those originally configured during installation.

Answer (score 1):

Neil Sly suffered from a similar problems, and documented his struggles (and eventual resolution) [on his blog](http://nrs.posterous.com/moss-deployment-failures).

Have you tried following the steps in his article?

Comment: No, I didn't read, I was had to reinstall WSS 3.0, and it resolved the issue. It seems that problem occur when I made changes to the accounts, under SPTimerV3 and SPAdmin services are started.